# Deep learning models with different input size?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

All the models i've used are particularly training for data that has same input size, either image or vectors.

I recently encounter a problem that i want to solve using deep learning approach.

Let's say we use characteristics to describe a city(there are millions attributes, fix size but too many), and a country may contains different number of cities, at the end we want to verify which continent is this country from.

So the input is something like:

```
country A :{<city_1 attributes: 1, 3, ...> ... <city_n attributes: 21, 11, 294,...>}
...
...
...
country N :{<city_x attributes: 55, 21, ...> ... <city_n attributes: 25, 2, ...>}

*index represents corresponding entry in characteristics database that has millions entries.
```

I can tranform the data to something like

```
< <1, 4, 32> <23, 55, 203123, ...> ... <2, 4 ,23 ...> >
...
...
...
< <21, 55, 87...> <5> ...>
```

There are two problems

1. characteristics of city are too many, cant represent as in one-hot encoding form.
2. The number of cities in each entry are different and no upper bound assumed.

I'm not sure this is a good example, but you get the idea.
I can only think of RNN, however the data in this case are totally independent with no sequential relationship between each city.

Any suggestion is appreciated and welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm let's see:

I am going to start with the easy one:

2: why don't you just train a classifier where the input are the attributes of the cities and the output is the country?

1: You don't have to represent as one-hot enconding. If you have too many features and want to reduce the number, why don't you try some feature analysis? Some come to my mind: Pearson correlation (maybe your inputs are correlated and don't add new info), you could use random forest to determine if the inputs are important to the output (if I want to predict stock prices, maybe knowing the phase of the moon is not important)... you could also reduce the dimension of the features with tools such as PCA or SVD, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- Since the data is not images, nor is it time sequence it will be better to go with N-layer Neural network
- Since the input size is variable, you can use something like an autoencoder to obtain a fixed length representation of your input data.
- This length of feature vector might be a hyperparameter tuned for your dataset
- This in the end, you ll have a fixed length vector representation of this variable length data
- If the input data is text, you can first tokenize it[using spacy,gensim etc.] and then use a simple tf-idf or bag of words approach to build a simple 2D feature representation and then pass this through the autoencoder to obtain a fixed length representation
- A RNN/LSTM can be used if semantic information needs to be captured